# SQLite print out history using lag() function

Tags: database, sqlite

I am using lag() function to get the data from the preceding row, however, in the case with a first row where there is no previous price, I want to use price from the same row for the subtraction.
I have tried using case statement, so if the return value of the lag() function is more than zero then the value from the previous row will be used, otherwise value from the same row is used.
This is how m query looks like but I keep getting syntax errors...

```
select p.buy_price - case when lag(p.buy_price, 1, 0) over (partition by p.id_stock order by pd.id_date asc) > 0 then lag(p.buy_price, 1, 0) over (partition by p.id_stock order by pd.id_date asc) else p.buy_price end) buy_history
```

Comment: You have an extra closing paren in that, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lag()` takes an optional third argument that is used as a default if there is no matching previous row. You're using it, actually, but making it overly complicated Something like

```
select p.buy_price - lag(p.buy_price, 1, p.buy_price) over (partition by p.id_stock order by pd.id_date) as buy_history
```

should work.